# Excel can't find Excel-Dna.xll after Windows update

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

Developed Excel-DNA project in C# using .Net6. User installed SDK and was able to run. After windows / excel update started to fail with this message.

["Microsoft Excel cannot access the file xyz.xll.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhXos.jpg)

Comment: have you checked the permissions for the file folder is it even there

Comment: The folder is there and all the binaries etc. I know some companies don't allow changes to C: which is why its set up for C:\temp. This should be fine but I will check there wasn't some policy update that doesn't allow it. Good idea nbk.

Comment: Temp is a bad name, a comprehensive name, would be better to avoid misunderstandings

Comment: If you put something in the temp folder, it's liable to get deleted eventually.